# Get current metamask account method not working anymore

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript

I was using the following method to access the selected account on metamask through web3 v1:

```
  //metamask method that refresh the active account in the web
    this.web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on('update',async function(event){
      this.setState({
        account: event.selectedAddress.toLowerCase()
      },()=>{
        this.load();
      });
    }.bind(this));
```

And everything was working fine, it seems that a new update happened and this is no longer available. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `accountsChanged` event:

```
  /**
   * Listening for MetaMask address changes.
   * @param  {Function} callback Resolve when address is changed
   */
   function onAccountsChanged(callback) {
     ethereum.on('accountsChanged', (accounts) => {
       // Time to reload your interface with accounts[0]
       console.log(accounts);

       callback(null, accounts[0]);
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

test this change on account:

```
this.web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on('update',async function(event){
  this.setState({
    account: this.web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress.toLowerCase()
  },()=>{
    this.load();
  });
}.bind(this));
```